# Method defined in class doesn't return anything when called in main

Tags: c++, class, oop, stl

I don't understand why twoSum method inside the Solution class does not output anything when called in main. Please tell me why. The program should output the positions of two numbers that are together equal to target variable. There is only one valid set with this property. You can find this problem on leetcode:

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
using std::vector;
using std::map;
class Solution {
public:
        vector <int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        map <int,int> mymap;
        vector <int> res;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            mymap[nums[i]]=i;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            int result = target - nums[i];
            if(mymap.find(result)!=mymap.end() && mymap[result] != i)
            {
                res.push_back(i);
                res.push_back(mymap[result]);

                return res;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

};
int main()
{
    vector<int> nums(4);
    int target;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        std:: cin>> nums[i];
        std:: cout<<nums[i]<<' ';
    }
    std:: cin>>target;
    Solution abc;
    abc.twoSum(nums,target);
    return 0;
}
```

///For array=[1,2,3,4] and target= 6, i expected the output to be [1,3]. Instead it doesn't print out anything

Comment: That's because you do not print anything ‍♂️

Comment: `twoSum` does not have any IO, so how would it display anything?

Comment: You also ignore the return value of `twoSum`.

Comment: You are not storing the return value from the function anywhere. You are also not even *trying* to print what the function returns. Why you expect any output I don't understand.

Comment: I think you're confusing "output" as in "something printed on the console", and "output" as in "a value returned by a function". The latter is invisible unless the code that calls the function takes the value and prints it.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing "output" as in "something printed on the console", and "output" as in "a value returned by a function".

The `abc.twoSum(nums,target);` call in main **returns** a vector of ints. In C and C++ return values may be ignored and then are simply lost.

If you want something to be printed you have to store the return value of the function in a variable or use it directly and then actually print it.